# How to determine which version of a kernel header file is used in a particular build

Tags: c, linux, build, linux-kernel, header-files

I'm trying to understand the Linux kernel, so I'm reading Linux kernel source. So how can I determine where a header file located, because there are many header files have the same name but locate in different directories?

Example: they include fcntl.h in fs/open.c

I can find fcntl.h in 17 different directories

```
arch/alpha/include/asm/fcntl.h
arch/arm/include/asm/fcntl.h
....
```

Comment: The examples you list are unique for various types of processor, likely only one (or at most two) of those would be a possible candidate for use by a build for a given piece of hardware.  However there might also be other possibilities from which it can sometimes be challenging to determine which is used - for example, there will be a derived copy with the C library for userspace programs to link against which will match details of the architecture specific one in the kernel sources.

Comment: Most compilers will let you know where they are searching if you ask them politely. gcc `--verbose` does that I reckon.

Comment: This is absolutely a real question, covering a real and frequent problem.  Can only assume that those closing it have never tried to modify a kernel module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's going to depend on the way the file was [included](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). If included with quotes like this:

```
#include "QuotedHeader.h"
```

It *should* be in the same directory. (It can also be in the "include" directories.)
If included with angle brackets like this:

```
#include <BracketedHeader.h>
```

It's located in an "include" directory. These are directories that the compiler is told at compile-time to search in for header files. These can be passed as parameters, or set in an environment variable.

For the examples provided, the directories make it clear why there are duplicates: generally, different architecture-specific files are separated by folders named for different [architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures).
In the example provided, you're looking at different fcntl.h files for the [Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha) and [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) architectures. The file your compiler will use depends on the CPU being compiled for, and the compiler will be told which to use during compile time.

In my personal opinion, if you don't already know this, you may be starting in the wrong place to understand the linux kernel. Try first researching C

Comment: I definitely agree with the personal opinion. Kernel source code is quite complex, and you should be very fluent on C programming before daring dive inside it. Try first to understand how some application (e.g. your shell's source code) is compiled, and how its source code is designed. Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ or other good book.

Answer (score 1):

You could add  [preprocessor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to the `CFLAGS` governing the compilation of your kernel module. In particular, the `-H` option (passed to `gcc`) displays the path of each `#include`-d header, and `-I` option augments the list of searched include directories.

Answer (score -1):

Look up the name of the header file in the man pages...or google it.